# "Gateway of last resort is not set" even though I have a default route to a tunnel interface

Tags: cisco, routing, router, tunnel, interface

I work with Cisco CSRs.  On all of my previous CSRs in AWS, I have the following:

```
AWS-ENV-CSR-R1#sh run | in ip route
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Tunnel1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Tunnel2 2

AWS-ENV-CSR-R1#sh ip cef 1.2.3.4
0.0.0.0/0
attached to Tunnel1

AWS-ENV-CSR-R1#sh ip route

Gateway of last resort is 0.0.0.0 to network 0.0.0.0

S* 0.0.0.0/0 is directly connected, Tunnel1
```

However, in my Azure environment, I have the following:

```
MAZ-ENV-CSR-1-R1#sh run | in ip route
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Tunnel1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Tunnel2 2

MAZ-ENV-CSR-1-R1#sh ip route

Gateway of last resort is not set

MAZ-ENV-CSR-1-R1#sh ip cef 1.2.3.4
0.0.0.0/0
no route
```

Are there any ideas as to why this shows that the gateway is not set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the interface to which your static route points is not up, then the route is withdrawn from the routing table. You can only route to an `UP/UP` interface.

Apparently, both tunnels to which your static default routes point are down. If you bring up a tunnel, then the route will be placed into the routing table.